# What should the on-topic section of our Help Center contain?

Tags: discussion, help-center

Our current /help/on-topic page is just the default boilerplate, and doesn't really help new users learn what kind of questions are on-topic here. It's definitely in need of improvement.

**What topics should the Help Center cover?** I have posted a single Community Wiki answer containing our current /help/on-topic page (that you should feel free to edit and improve), but you can also post answers of your own if you have ideas for what the page should contain but don't want to actually write them.

Answer (score 2):

The following is the current draft of what our new /help/on-topic page should look like. Edit this Community Wiki answer with your improvements!

---

### What topics can I ask about here?

Please limit your questions to specific issues with the Vi and Vim family of editors.

Please [look around](https://vi.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer).

If your question is not specifically on-topic for Vi and Vim Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a list of most common on-topic forks, and most common off-topic vi-like thingies should be provided. In the second category, I mean mainly the bash vi extension, firefox vi extension, etc.

Comment: A link to [this meta question](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/7/88) could also be provided.

Comment: @Doorknob I thought about it, too. It's sounds like a rather good idea :)