# Are you [mods] seriously think that neovim is `off-topic` for vi/vim stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking this question because this question [Neovim takes so long to source ruby.vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15597/neovim-takes-so-long-to-source-ruby-vim)
have been put on hold.

Answer (score 6):

Nobody said Neovim is off-topic on this site (neither the [meta question about this](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-is-considered-to-be-vi) or the current [help center](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) nor its [future revision](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1445/1841)). We even have a dedicated [tag](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neovim) with a lot of questions about Neovim.

Carpetsmoker closed the question because the performance issue didn't come from Vim itself but came from a third party tool (`rbenv`) which is clearly off topic.

Comment: I don't agree that this question is off topic. The question is "why is sourcing ruby.vim slow" and the answer is "because of your ruby environment: Vim is waiting for ruby to do stuff". I agree that figuring out how to *fix* that would be off-topic, but that's not what the OP asked.

Answer (score 4):

The vote for close was because the problem was **related to ruby**, not to neovim. Note, that I'd have said to run nvim with `strace` and then check were the time was lost.

Now the problem could be changed into: *"how could I know when my performance problem is related to vim or to an external process or device that takes to long to respond?"*

I had the problem a few times because my runtime files are on an overloaded GPFS device, and that a few option like `&tags` contained `**` which triggered a lot useless calls to `stat` and to `fopen`.